# Get Span Tag Id in a tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, vbscript, dom-events

I'm trying to get id of the span tag that is M24 by using Javascript function.

```
  <a HREF="javascript:void(0)"><font color="#000080"><span id=M24>2012-2013</span></font
 color="#000080"></a>
```

I m using the following code but its not returning any value:

```
 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
function clickHandler()
{
  var xid=document.getElementID(this);
    alert("Span id is "+xid);

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewrite the function like the one below

```
function clickHandler()
{
  var xid=document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    alert("Span id is "+xid[0].id);

}
```

To find out multiple span id's

```
function clickHandler()
{
  var xid=document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for(var i=0;i<xid.length;i++){
     alert("Span id is "+xid[i].id);
 }
```

instead of above functions you can simply do this, rewrite your function like this

```
function clickHandler(evt)
{
  var e = window.event || evt;
  var spanid = e.target.id;//to know on which span user has clicked.  
}
```

and add your span's like this

```
<span id=M24 onclick="clickHandler(evt);">2012-2013</span>
<span id=M25 onclick="clickHandler(evt);">2012-2013</span>
...so on....
```

Comment: there are multiple span tags in web page so i also need id of  particular  span as per click event.

Comment: you didnt answer for multiple span how can i get the id in that i can not pass the index 0 because user can select the span on any index.

Comment: check the answer again loop thru the list of spans and grab the id's of each span element

Comment: how will i check on which id user have clicked

Comment: please what is this coudnt get this                                              function clickHandler(evt)
{
  var e = window.event || evt;

Comment: have you not understood what i have been doing in this function

Answer (score 1):

It is `getElementById()`, not `getElementID()`

Currently this representation is not correct. Since if you know the tag ID then you should use `getElementById()`.

But in your case, use `getElementsByTagName()`